# How to find duplicate values according multiple columns and show both

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to find another examples, but I have not been able to find one that can help me

I am currently trying to find if the value in the STR_ROUTE column is in the STR_STREET column, as shown in the following example

| ID | STR_ROUTE | STR_STREET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAIN | Can |
| 2 | AV | CAL |
| 3 | CLL | CLL |
| 4 | STR | VAL |
| 5 | VAL | MIN |
| 7 | CAL | SQR |

in this example as the CAL and VAL values of the STR_ROUTE column are in STR_STREET the expected result is to display the following table with all occurrences

| ID | STR_ROUTE | STR_STREET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | AV | CAL |
| 4 | STR | VAL |
| 5 | VAL | MIN |
| 7 | CAL | SQR |

(The third row is not taken into consideration because it is the same registry.)

I was validating with this option, but I have not been able to succeed and does not take the rules into consideration.

1. It does not take into consideration if the repeated value is within
   the same record.
2. Both the repeated record and the record to which it is compared must be displayed.

> SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE STR_ROUTE IN (SELECT STR_STREET FROM TABLE WHERE STR_STREET)

Comment: Why did you include 2,AV,CAL in your expected results, when STR_ROUTE:AV does not occur in STR_STREET anywhere? Does your rule `if the value in the STR_ROUTE column is in the STR_STREET column` imply `and vice versa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the presence of values of each column in another column and union the results.

> ```
> with test_table(ID, STR_ROUTE, STR_STREET) as (
>   select 1, 'MAIN', 'Can' from dual union all
>   select 2, 'AV', 'CAL' from dual union all
>   select 3, 'CLL', 'CLL' from dual union all
>   select 4, 'STR', 'VAL' from dual union all
>   select 5, 'VAL', 'MIN' from dual union all
>   select 7, 'CAL', 'SQR' from dual
> )
> select *
> from test_table
> where str_route in (
>   select f.str_street
>   from test_table f
> )
>   and str_route != str_street
>
> union all
>
> select *
> from test_table
> where str_street in (
>   select f.str_route
>   from test_table f
> )
>   and str_route != str_street
> ```

> | ID | STR_ROUTE | STR_STREET |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5 | VAL | MIN |
> | 7 | CAL | SQR |
> | 2 | AV | CAL |
> | 4 | STR | VAL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ae811d6bbfe7e46e8866711d7bbc6487)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query and filter to only include the rows where the hierarchical query has descended to the second level and it is a leaf node or where the first level of the hierarchy is not a leaf (and there is a matching second level in the hierarchy):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 1 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 0
OR     LEVEL = 2 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR str_route = str_street;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, STR_ROUTE, STR_STREET) AS
SELECT 1, 'MAIN', 'Can' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'AV',   'CAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CLL',  'CLL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'STR',  'VAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'VAL',  'MIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'CAL',  'SQR' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | STR_ROUTE | STR_STREET |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5 | VAL | MIN |
> | 4 | STR | VAL |
> | 7 | CAL | SQR |
> | 2 | AV | CAL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cca713b8526bd49b27abb43f8a6ea397)*

Comment: this solution worked for me and it is more reduced than the other one but the only thing is that with the data handled it takes a little longer than the other solution but it worked very well.